# How can I install 32-bit packages on 64-bit Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, dpkg, 64-bit, 19.10

On all of the other posts with this question, it says to run `sudo apt-get install package-name:i386`, but this doesn't work for me. For example, here is the output of `sudo apt-get install -y libasound2-data:i386`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libasound2-data' instead of 'libasound2-data:i386'
libasound2-data is already the newest version (1.1.9-0ubuntu1.2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I did already run `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

Comment: Run `dpkg -l | grep "libasound"`.

Comment: @Liso
```ii  libasound2:amd64                           1.1.9-0ubuntu1.2                       amd64        shared library for ALSA applications
ii  libasound2-data                            1.1.9-0ubuntu1.2                       all          Configuration files and profiles for ALSA drivers
ii  libasound2-plugins:amd64                   1.1.9-0ubuntu1                         amd64        ALSA library additional plugins```

Comment: the available and installable package are shown with `apt-show-versions | grep i386`